# Count row once if it contains "A"

Tags: google-sheets

I have four columns of data. I want to count the row once if any of the four cells in each row contains an "A".

Here's a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10hZuOgdL3Pf3-yLsK1G4DlVIThGR0fWBL_IEMpn5vnY/edit?usp=sharing

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(N(mmult(n(regexmatch(B4:E15,"A")),transpose(column(B4:E15)))>0)))
```

or

```
=sumproduct(N(mmult(n(regexmatch(B4:E15,"A")),transpose(column(B4:E15)))>0))
```

to get the row totals and count the ones which are greater than zero.

[image]

This is case sensitive.