# count row once if it contains a "1" for a large data set

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have a large dataset (say 7 columns with 941 rows) in Google Sheets.

For each row, if it contains a 1 (that value being returned by a formula in a said cell) in any column, I want it to be counted once.

I did some research and found these two threads.

- [previous - count row if contains an 'A'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651215/count-row-once-if-it-contains-a)
- [previous - count row if    it contains a number](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/7sw7z1/check_if_any_cell_in_a_row_has_a_number/)
  [my example sheet of what I tried](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1niTYQCA0ZPrOR5_13eSpvhkuhNIqqMX9F7A8pNZfaKQ/edit?usp=sharing)

So I used the Arrayformula from the previous StackOverflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651215/count-row-once-if-it-contains-a). I made a table with 'x' instead of 1 to try it out. It works - but only for a max of 200 rows (or so) at a time. Apparently it is hitting a maximum number of values for arrayformula (40k?). So I guess I could count all my 941 rows... 200 at a time and then adding those together? Is there a more elegant workaround?

I tried the countif formula from the Reddit link [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/7sw7z1/check_if_any_cell_in_a_row_has_a_number/) (which should count each row once if it contains a number) and couldn't even get it to work for a smaller data set (see sheet) - no idea what I'm doing wrong!

So to restate, I'm looking for help figuring out how to create a single formula to count a row once if it contains a 1 in any column - for a data set that's some 900+ rows and multiple columns.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work if your 7 columns are A:G.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(MMULT(N(A2:G=1),SEQUENCE(7,1,1,0))>0)))
```